# SQL синтакс, выбор значений даже если их нет

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT  `time`.*, client.first_name, client.last_name, client.phone FROM `time` 
JOIN orders ON `time`.id = orders.id_time
JOIN client ON orders.id_client = client.id
WHERE `time`.`date` = '2017-05-15' AND `time`.id_doctor = 1
```

Нужно переделать запрос, чтобы из `time` вывелись значения, которых нет в `orders` и `client`.

Comment: Используйте left join + условие where orders.id is null && client.id is null

Comment: Ну вот лично как по мне нисколько не дубликат, поскольку ответа на вопрос не дает. Даже в графическом плане они отличаются: [joins](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Hn3FFOQE5yo/UzMiH9LkaHI/AAAAAAAAA1U/FAgoy-o-gs8/s1600/SQL_JOINS_SET_OPERATORS.jpg)

Comment: @AlexKrass А условие с проверкой на NULL зачем и почему не дубликат. Ведь заголовок вопроса "выбор значений _даже_ если их нет". Как по мне, так такая формулировка означает "выбрать те, где значения есть и те, где их нет", да и присутствие в списке выборки полей из clients подсказывает, что они все таки интересны и там ожидаются не только NULL

Comment: @Mike то есть я неправильно понимаю сути вопроса? Ну может быть, пускай тогда тс смотрит и думает, ему все-таки виднее.

Comment: Ребят, вопрос решен, тот кто столкнется с данной проблемой, решается таким образом, вместо "JOIN" пишется "LEFT OUTER JOIN " селектит данные которые сравниваются из других таблиц и которых нет.